# How to create a floating back button in Android?

Tags: android, accessibility, android-windowmanager

I am trying to create an app similar to Samsung assist menu or Pie Control app.

I created the floating button using WindowManager.

```
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

And then I created simple list of options to perform using dialog box.

This is how I perform going to home button using following code:

```
Intent startHome = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startHome.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startHome.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startHome);
```

Now I would like to know how to perform back button action similar to hardware back key of the device that is NOT rooted.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: why you are not using FAB from support library ?

Comment: I am creating a floating button over layer that shows up on every application and even lock screen. FAB will only work in one application and it's for different purpose.

Comment: so backButton functionality? then I didnt get it ? please explain

Comment: Similar to: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Vwm46N7VCzFC5X_faJ-ZdjhUpddEnOBJkqa6lX70q8I6mi_Kh0JicyXM47PPpBAcJrg=h900

Comment: On the back button clicked, you would like to close only the activity of your app (when it is showing) or any activity from any application that is currently showing on the screen?

Comment: @user1294998 any activity from any application that is currently showing on the screen